# How to Set Tableview CustomCell Height programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I make a UITableview that Contain CustomCell. My CustomCell contain UITextView and Some other Controls but I want to set My Cell Height like as 300 if my UITextViewtext Contain Some text and if my TextView text is Contain null text means not any Text then I want my Cell Height 170 how it possible. I write a code for that but it is not working.

My code like as

```
NSString *magazineDescription=[self.firstArray valueForKey:@"long_description"];
if([magazineDescription isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    cellOne.magazineDescriptionTextView.text = magazineDescription;
    cellOne.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
}
else
{
    cellOne.magazineDescriptionTextView.text =  @"";
    cellOne.magazineDescriptionTextView.hidden=TRUE;
    cellOne.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 170);
}
```

Here my self.firstArray Contain JSON data value and sometime my keyValue @"long_description" is null so I want to hide The TextView From Cell and Set height of Cell from 300 to 170 and Width are want to remaining same for both cases.

I know the method for this like as:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But in this method how to set height in this Method for this Case .please give me Solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = @“Your text”;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:YourFontSize];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(TextviewWidth, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    NSLog(@"labelSize : %f", labelSize.height);
    return labelSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Fetch your string from array as below or according to your code
    NSString *magazineDescription=[self.firstArray valueForKey:@"long_description"];
    if(magazineDescription!=nil)
    {
        return 300.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        return 170.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code here and array you you are passing to tableview

Comment: NSString *magazineDescription=[self.firstArray valueForKey:@"long_description"];
            if([magazineDescription isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                cellOne.magazineDescriptionTextView.text = magazineDescription;
                cellOne.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
     }
     else
     {
     cellOne.magazineDescriptionTextView.text =  @"";
     cellOne.magazineDescriptionTextView.hidden=TRUE;
     cellOne.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 170);
     }
    [cellOne.magazineDescriptionTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"RobotoCondensed-Light" size:10.0f]];

Comment: and i write to try your code like as
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NSString *magazineDescription=[self.firstArray valueForKey:@"long_description"];
        if (magazineDescription != nil)
        {
            return 300;
        }
        else
        {
            return 170;
        }
    }
    return 140;
}

Comment: try magazineDescription.length > 0 instead of magazineDescription != nil...  Also print the value of magazineDescription

Comment: it it always print null bro

Comment: Does your tableView have section as well as you are trying to compare indexPath.section in method of heightForRowAtIndexPath which means each cell row will be affected by this. Please print the value of self.firstArray here and also what value are you try to insert into each cell as you need to extract the value at each index of array for different cell.

Answer (score 0):

First, declare the CustomerCell to the property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomerCell *cell;
```

in the tableViewDelegate

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([@"" isEqualToString:_cell.textView.text] || _cell.textView.text == nil) {
        return 170;
    } else {
        return 300;
    }
}
```

hope it`s help